# jQuery - How can I stop appending connect to an element selected by class?

Tags: jquery, append

I have a page that describes various options that people can implemenet. To better define these explanations I have an icon that reveals a large relevant image on hover.

The html for this would look something like (for simplicity I have included only 2 elements with class x but in reality there would be a lot more)

```
<div id="innerlayout">
 <ul>
  <li>Content for 1
   <a class="x" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="large-image-1.jpg" title="Caption for Large Image 1">
    <img src="learn-more.jpg" alt="Learn More Icon" width="30" height="30" />
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>Content for 2
   <a class="x" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="large-image-2.jpg" title="Caption for Large Image 2">
    <img src="learn-more.jpg" alt="Learn More Icon" width="30" height="30" />
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The jQuery I currently have looks like this.

```
$document.ready(function() {
 $('a.x', $('#innerlayout')).hover(
  function () {
   var path = $(this).attr('rel');
   var text = $(this).attr('title');
   $(this).append($("<p class='revealer'><img src='"+path+"' /><br />"+text+"</p>"));
   $('p.revealer').hide().fadeIn(500);
  }, 
  function () {
   $(this).find('p:last').remove();
  }
 );
});
```

This works fine but I was looking to change it so that the appended paragraph was hidden rather than removed, the class of the <a> tag changed to something other than "x" and subsequent hovers of this newly classed <a> would show the now existing content. I came up with this, but this continues to append the content on each subsequent hover despite the changed <a> element class. Can anyone suggest to me what I'm doing wrong here, and how I might fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a.x', $('#innerlayout')).hover(
  function () {
   var path = $(this).attr('rel');
   var text = $(this).attr('title');
   $(this).append($("<p class='revealer'><img src='"+path+"' /><br />"+text+"</p>"));
   $('p.revealer').hide().fadeIn(500);
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find('p:last').hide();
    $(this).removeClass('x').addClass('revealed');
  }
 );
 $('a.revealed', $('#innerlayout')).hover(
  function() {
   $(this).find('p').show();
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find('p').hide();
    }
 );
});
```

Comment: Would you mind creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NU7e5/) is happening with your code.

Comment: @juzerali Exactly, sorry not used fiddle before but will bear it in mind for future questions.

Comment: Class `x` is not removed on `mousein`, it is infact removed on `mouseout` so you are appending before the class `x` is removed from the DOM element.
EDIT: Since you are using `$(this)` elements will be appended even if you remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your line `$(this).append($("<p class='revealer'><img src='"+path+"' /><br />"+text+"</p>"));`. This is what you are doing wrong. Appending the element on each hover. If you are appending than make sure you remove this element on `mouseout`. Otherwise append it on `load`, keep it hidden, and `show` it on `hover` or `mousein`.

Comment: why does it continue to append with the selector $('a.x') when this class has been changed so in theory $('a.revealed') would need to be the selector?

Comment: Class `x` is not removed on mousein, it is infact removed on mouseout so you are appending before the class `x` is removed from the DOM element. Since you are using $(this) elements will be appended even if you remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$(this).append($("<p class='revealer'><img src='"+path+"' /><br />"+text+"</p>"));
```

You can try

```
$(this).html("your content") //if you want to replace the whole content
```

otherwise create a div or span tag and just replace that particular tag.

Hope this solves your question.